# Robocopy, xCopy or other solution?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy, robocopy

I need to a way to update all files in a destination folder and its sub-directories with  files in a single source folder.

Source : File A, File B, File C
Destination : File A, Destination->SubFolder : File B

It needs to update File A and File B in their dest folder and also ignore File C as it does not exist anywhere in dest.

Is this possible with xcopy or robocopy or is there another tool that will do the job? I've been having a play bit can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

robocopy will definitely help you out.  While it doesn't sound like you can straight merge the source and destination outright (source sounds flat while the destination has some hierarchy), it has commands for copying entire folders and not copying if destination files aren't there.

Comment: Ditto, xcopy. Sounds like using either tool you'd need to have a recursive loop, copying files from source to (current) destination only if file is already there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp). This is a open-source, GUI windows version of the [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) tool. Some of its features are

- Incremental backup - Copies part of the file that is actually modified (so saving time and network resources).
- Task scheduler - Profiles in DeltaCopy can run based on a schedule.
- Windows friendly environment.
- Complex Ignore patterns (filter files by name, extension, size, path or other criteria).

Answer (score 0):

you can use ROBOCOPY like that

```
robocopy E:\Source G:\Destination\SubFolder /e /mir /np /log:backup_log.txt
```

for more [info](http://repiarandecovery.com/robocopy-commands-and-overview/#.UZSzJLWl5SM)